# Clicking event not working in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery and below is my code, my problem is that no matter what the click events do not work.

I am able to log the `qid` i.e question id using the `console.log(qid)` properly

```
function prepareQuestionHtml(questionList){

    var questions = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < questionList.length; i++){
        var questionId = questionList[i].qid;
        questions += "<div class='ui-link qst' id='" + questionId + "' >" + questionList[i].qst + "</div>";

        (function () {
            var qid = questionId;
            console.log(qid);
            $("#" + qid).click(function(){
                console.log("aaaaa");
                openAnswer(localStorage.selected_category, qid);
            });
        })();
    }
    $("#category-content").html(questions);
}

function openAnswer(category, questionId)
{
    console.log(category, questionId);
}
```

What could be the problem here ? Even the statement `console.log("aaaaa");` is not reached on click of the links.

EDIT :

I am using the following two JS files

- jquery.min.js
- jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js

Comment: Using functions (your click function) within a for loop is considered a bad idea. Hope it makes sense

Comment: @roXon can you suggest an alternative ?

Comment: Try `$("#" + qid).on("click",function(){` and wrap the function call in $(function() {}) instead of having in INSIDE the function

Comment: @Yasser just find a way to use it outside the for loop, and target newly generated elements using the object event delegation (click) using `.on()` method like : `$('#parent').on('click','.dynamicElement', function(){`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've shortened your code to this:

```
var questions = '';

for(var i = 0; i < questionList.length; i++){
    var questionId = questionList[i].qid;
    questions += "<div class='ui-link qst' id='" + questionId + "' >" + questionList[i].qst + "</div>";

    // attach click handler to `#questionId`
}
$("#category-content").html(questions);
```

The problem here is that you're trying to attach a click handler **before the nodes are inserted** into the DOM.

A quick hack:

```
(function (qid) {
    console.log(qid);
    $("#category-content").on('click', "#" + qid, function() {
        console.log("aaaaa");
        openAnswer(localStorage.selected_category, qid);
    });
})(questionId);
```

However, I would recommend doing a single click handler:

```
$('#category-content').on('click', '.qst', function() {
    // handle the click here
});
```

I wasn't sure why you're using `this.openAnswer()`. By default `this` would be bound to the element that was clicked and that element probably doesn't have that method.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function prepareQuestionHtml(questionList){

    var questions = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < questionList.length; i++){
        var questionId = questionList[i].qid;
        questions += "<div class='ui-link qst' id='" + questionId + "' >" + questionList[i].qst + "</div>";
    }

    $("#category-content")
      .html(questions)
      .on('click', 'ui-link', function(){
        var $this = $(this)
          , qid   = $this.attr('id')
        ;//var

        openAnswer(localStorage.selected_category, qid);
      })
    ;//#category-content
}

function openAnswer(category, questionId)
{
    console.log(category, questionId);
}
```

Comment: my bad just added this.openAnswer, will remove it, not working without that too

Comment: even the `console.log("aaaaa");' is not reached

Comment: I am using `jquery.min.js` and `jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js`. All my functions are declared inside `$(document).ready(function(){});`

Comment: just ran the code u wrote, the event was not fired and `console.log( $('#' + qid) );` was always logged as `[]` I just tried the other answer by Jack and it worked. Thank you for your answer. Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

This has a better chance of working

```
function openAnswer(category, questionId)
{
    console.log(category, questionId);

}

$(function () {
  var questionList = {};
  var container = $("#category-content")
    for(var i = 0; i < questionList.length; i++){
        var questionId = questionList[i].qid;
        container.append("<div class='ui-link qst' id='" + questionId + "' >" + questionList[i].qst + "</div>");

    }

    container.on('click', '.qst',function() {
            console.log("aaaaa");
            openAnswer(localStorage.selected_category, this.id);
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a best candidate for [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and the [data API](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

```
function prepareQuestionHtml(questionList){
    var questions = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < questionList.length; i++){
        var questionId = questionList[i].qid;
        questions += '<div data-qid="' + questionId + '" class='ui-link qst' id='' + questionId + '' >' + questionList[i].qst + '</div>';
    }
    $('#category-content').html(questions);
}

$(function(){
    $('#category-content').on('click', '.qst', function(e){
        openAnswer(localStorage.selected_category, $(e.currentTarget).data('qid'));
    });
});

function openAnswer(category, questionId) {
    console.log(category, questionId);
}
```

Here we register a single click event to the container node with listens to any click in the `.qst` element. When the click happens we fetch the `qid` data (`data-qid`) stored in the element.

Comment: Would be prudent to execute prepare inside the $(function... No?

Comment: no `prepare` is a function, it should be declared in the global name space, but this method should be called once the dom is ready